# Handle multiple clients with one server

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I try to get a connection to multiple clients using the Sockets in Java. Everything seems to work, but the problem is, that the server just listens to the first client. If there are multiple clients, the server can send them all messages, but he can just listen to the messages that came from the first client. I tried this all out (I'm at this problem since yesterday). So I'm pretty sure, that the fault has to be in the class "ClientListener".

Explanation:
There is a List with clients (connection to communicate with Strings). In the GUI there is a list, where I can choose, with which client I'd like to communicate. If I change the client, the variable `currentClient` (int) switches to another number

`networkClients` is an ArrayList, where all the different connections are "stored".

The first connected client is exactly the same as the other clients, there is nothing special about him. He is called, when the variable `currentClient` is set to 0 (per default). The variable-switching is working. Like I said, all the clients give me a response if I send them an order, but just networkClients.get(0) is heard by the server (ClientListener).

```
class ClientListener implements Runnable {
String request;

@Override
public void run() {
  try {
    while (networkClients.size() < 1) {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    //***I'm pretty sure, that the problem is in this line
    while ((request = networkClients.get(currentClient).getCommunicationReader().readLine()) != null) {
    //***
       myFileList.add(new MyFile(request));
    }
   }
   } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

I hope someone can help me. I tried many things, but nothing worked.

EDIT: Like I wrote in the code example, is it possible that the while-loop isn't able to switch the number of "currentClient" (which is handled by another Thread)? I tested/simulated something similar in a testclass and the result was, that a while-loop of course can can update the state in it (meaning, that if a variable changes in the () of a while loop, it will of course be checked after every repeat).

Comment: http://www.ase.md/~aursu/ClientServerThreads.html

Comment: I know how to set something like this up. But I just have an error in the code, that doesn't allow me to read strings from multiple clients, even I can send strings to multiple clients (without problems). So the problem aren't the basics. I hope someone can help me with this code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

The Thread sits in the declared method I mentioned in the starting post (in the code snippet) and waits unlimited time for a new response of the client.
So changing the index of the list "`networkClients`" won't do anything, because nothing will happen there, until there is a new order sent by the client (which lets the thread go further).

So you need to implement an extra listener for each client.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [multithreading](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm).

Your server program should be made out of:

```
- The main thread
- A thread that handles new connections.
(Upon creating a new connection, start a new thread and pass the connection on to that thread)
- A thread for each connected client, listening to the each client separately
```

Take a look at some examples like: [(1)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm) [(2)](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/multithreaded-server.html)

Comment: I'm not totally new to multithreading (even this example looks like a school-chat), so I know the basics and my while loop should normally work. I don't know whats happening. I did everything you wrote there, except the "listener for every client", because I don't need this. I just need a peer to peer connections at the time. If I switch, the others should be ignored, and just the number "currentUser" should change to another one. :)
Everything else would be an overhead in my opinion (at least, for what I need). Anyway, thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: Without a 'new connection thread', it is not possible to have multiple clients connected. When a client connects, this `Socket` object of this connection should be passed on to the 'client thread' and the variable should be emptied in the 'connection thread'. This way each client thread will be completely independent and other threads won't be able to interfere with the client and server's client thread.

Comment: Finally I found the solution. You were right, that I have to use different Threads as readers BUT just because the Thread always waits in the declared method (in my code in the starterpost). I can change the number of the client, but this won't do anything, because the programm waits there until a new string is incoming.
I +1-ed your answer, but I will later write my own one, which brings this to a point.
Thank you very much for your help. :)